# average of pairs sitting next to each other - exoected value

Tags: probability

At the film screening "for the singles" spóźniło 15 singles: 8 men and 7 women. Since it is already dark, and latecomers do not want to disturb others, all randomly sit in the first row, which has 16 seats (so one too much). How much will the average male-female couples sitting next to each other?

My attempt:
$X$- - the number of pairs (girl+boy( sitting next to each other )
$X_i$ - the number of such settings that accurately and couples sitting next to each other 
$EX = EX_0 + EX_1 + ... + EX_{14}$
All settings is $N = 8\cdot {16\choose 8  }$
Every setting is is equally likely, so:
I can't compute number of settings that we have $i$ pairs.
Could help me, please  ?

Answer (score 2):

Each couple takes two seats chosen at random. There are $15$ pairs of contiguous seats and ${16\choose2}=8\times15$ pairs of seats hence each man-woman couple is seated next to each other with probability $\frac18$. There are $8\times 7$ man-woman couples hence the mean number of man-woman couples seated next to each other is $8\times7\times\frac18=7$.

For $w$ women and $m$ men seating on $s\geqslant w+m$ seats, the mean number of man-woman couples seated next to each other is $2\times w\times m\times\dfrac1s$.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 chances in 16 that the spare seat is at the end, with 14 places for boy/girl pairs.
There are 14 chances in 16 that the spare seat is not at the end, and 13 places for boy/girl pairs.
Given a pair of people there is (8*7+7*8)/(15*14)=8/15 chance they are boy/girl.
With 14 places, I expect 14*(8/15) boy/girl pairs.  With 13 places, I expect 13*(8/15) pairs.
Overall, I expect (2/16)(14*(8/15))+(14/16)(13*(8/15)) pairs.
Let A be the situation with a spare seat at the end, and B have the spare seat elsewhere.
$E(X_i)=8/15$
$E(\sum_iX_i|A)=14E(X_i)$
$E(\sum_iX_i|B)=13E(X_i)$
$E(\sum_iX_i)=E(A)E(\sum_iX_i|A)+E(B)E(\sum_iX_i|B)$

Comment: I don't understand. Could you solve it with using expected value ?

Answer (score 0):

Every pair of contiguous chairs has a probability
of $\frac{8}{16}\times\frac{7}{15}+\frac{7}{16}\times\frac{8}{15}$
that it will give place to a boy/girl combination.

There are exactly $15$ pairs of contiguous chairs.

Numbering these pairs and saying that $X_{i}=1$ if it gives place
to a boy/girl combination and $X_{i}=0$ otherwise, we find $\mathbb{E}X_{i}=P\left(X_{i}=1\right)=\frac{8}{16}\times\frac{7}{15}+\frac{7}{16}\times\frac{8}{15}$.

Then $X:=X_{1}+\cdots+X_{15}$ is the number of boy/girl combinations, and:

$$\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}X_{1}+\cdots+\mathbb{E}X_{15}=15\times\left(\frac{8}{16}\times\frac{7}{15}+\frac{7}{16}\times\frac{8}{15}\right)=7$$